# Sum cell values incrementally and print value when reaching specific sum or more?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to run through a column of number values in google spreadsheets (like in a "while" loop), incrementally suming the values and when reaching specific value print it in the corresponding cell?
Example:

[image]

So here I sum up all the elements in A column, when reaching >=40 I print the value, refresh the counter, and continue this iteration, counting till the end of the column.
So I get these portions of elements with approx. equals sum values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). In cell B2, put `=sumuntil(A2:A, 40)` where the code of `sumuntil`, entered in Script Editor, is

```
function sumuntil(arr, limit) {
  var out = [];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i in arr) {
    sum = sum + arr[i][0];
    if (sum >= limit) {
      out.push([sum]);
      sum = 0;
    }
    else {
      out.push([""]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it gives me an ERROR. And theres no autocomplete when I start typing "sumuntil". But I did put the function intro script editor. Don't understand what could be wrong.

Comment: error text "error of formula analysis"

Comment: There is no autocomplete, because it's a custom function. But it works in my spreadsheet exactly as shown, I tested before posting.

Comment: Oh, it was syntasyx error, had to use ";" instead of "," in "=sumuntil(A2:A; 40)". Thank you a lot!

Comment: Just one small question from me. Could you tell me please if there's a way to change fill background colors for the cells with values in B column? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, conditional formatting with "cell is not blank" or "value greater than zero"